# How to suppress returning a row in U-SQL IReducer

Tags: u-sql

On a condition I want to suppress returning a row in code behind for U-SQL REDUCE, I am not able to figure out the return statement for that.

To return a row as given in the documentation examples I used

**yield return output.AsReadOnly();**

Thanks,
Nasir

Answer (score 1):

The yield adds the returned row to the result enumerator. So I would assume that not yielding an output object will not add a row.